# How to correctly implement this IComparable?

Tags: c#

I have problems wit hthe implementation of a generic sorting algorithm.

We need to implement quicksort and selection sort, and a class which should be sortable using these functions. The functions should be generic, and thus work on other classes as well.

I tested the quicksort. It works perfectly on a List. However, when trying to execute it on my own comparable class, it says:

There is no implicit reference conversion from 'SNIP' to 'System.IComparable'

Do you guys have any idea what the problem can be?

Here is my comparable class:

```
    public class SNIP : IComparable
    { 
        private long lCost { get; set; }

        public SNIP(long lCost)
        {
            this.lCost = lCost;
        }

        public int CompareTo(object obj)
        {
            if (obj == null) return 1;

            SNIP oOtherPlank = obj as SNIP;
            if (oOtherPlank != null)
                return this.lCost.CompareTo(oOtherPlank.lCost);
            else
                throw new ArgumentException("Can only compare SNIPs.");
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please use text for code, not screenshots. And have you already tried the debugger?

Comment: Please don't post code as an image. Also, please show how you use the IComparable

Comment: Delete your own accidently created copy of `IComparable`.

Comment: @OliverWeichhold, I haven't accidentally created a copy of the interface.
 I included the code to my class as code now.

Comment: You need to implement `IComparable<SNIP>`, not the non-generic `IComparable`.

Comment: Show us the calling code please

Comment: @Sweeper, you were right! Thank you. I will answer the question below.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Sweeper, the comparable is now fixed.
Like he said, I had to define my class better:

```
public class SNIP : IComparable<SNIP>
    { 
        private long lCost { get; set; }

        public SNIP(long lCost)
        {
            this.lCost = lCost;
        }

        public int CompareTo(SNIP obj)
        {
            if (obj == null) return 1;

            SNIP oOtherSnip= obj as SNIP;
            if (oOtherSnip!= null)
                return this.lCost.CompareTo(oOtherSnip.lCost);
            else
                throw new ArgumentException("Can only compare SNIPs.");
        }
    }
```

It is also important to note that this only works when the argument of the CompareTo method is actually of the right class. I tried defining the class as IComparable before, but it didn't work because the argument in CompareTo was set to an object. By changing both the CompareTo header and the class header, the problem is fixed and the sorting now works.

Thanks a lot :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can implement *generic* `IComparable<SNIP>`, not `IComparable` which is very simple: `this` is always geater than `null` and if we compare with not null `other` we should check `lCost`.

```
public class SNIP : IComparable<SNIP>
{ 
    private long lCost { get; set; }

    public SNIP(long lCost)
    {
        this.lCost = lCost;
    }

    public int CompareTo(SNIP other) => other is null 
        ? 1
        : lCost.CompareTo(other.lCost);
}
```

then you can sort: note that since `List<SNIP>` is *generic*, the generic `IComparable<SNIP>` will be used on sorting.

```
List<SNIP> list = new List<SNIP>() 
{
    new SNIP(5),
    new SNIP(1),
    new SNIP(3),
};

list.Sort();
```